# Difference between mathematical interpolation and numerical interpolation?

Tags: education, interpolation, python

I have a data set of points. This data is not of full points. Instead, I have to generate a python code using `tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)` to interpolate the missing points between the values.

I want to describe the code but I dont know if I should say mathematical interpolation using a code or numerical interpolation?

Would someone please explain the difference

Comment: I never met those expressions. Interpolation is unambiguous. What makes you think that there are two concepts ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you for your reply. Because I am using a code rather than equation. So, I thought may be there is different way for expressing it. If I said a mathematical interpolation, I am not using an equation. Any suggestions how to describe it?

Comment: "If I said a mathematical interpolation, I am not using an equation.": what ??

Comment: Sorry, I know it is a bit confusing, please bear with me. I am trying to write my report and explain what I did in my data set. Part of the data set was interpolated using a code not an equation. Python provides 'tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)' for interpolation the values. So, would you please tell me if it is okay to say mathematical interpolation to describe the code?

Comment: It's ok to say interpolation. Mathematical interpolation won't be understood.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you very much.

Comment: @YvesDaoust have you used tck interpolate.bisplrep in python? If yes,would you please tell me how to explain it?

Comment: no, not at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for the reply